# Get Size of LLVM Type / "Dereference" Type

Tags: c++, llvm, llvm-ir, llvm-c++-api, llvm-codegen

This question is quite similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29979023/size-of-types-in-llvm), but I am not realy sure how to get the size in the following situation:

I have a Pointer type, e.g. `i32*`.

Now I would like to get the size of the 'pointed-to' type, so `i32` (aka 4).

Right now I am using the following code, that seems to work, but I am not sure if it is actualy correct:

```
Value *get_size(Type *t, IRBuilder<>& irb)
{
    Value *sizePtr = irb.CreateGEP(t->getContainedType(0),
            irb.CreateIntToPtr(ConstantInt::get(irb.getInt8Ty(), 0), t),
            ConstantInt::get(irb.getInt8Ty(), 1));

    return irb.CreatePtrToInt(sizePtr, irb.getInt64Ty());
}
```

(note: The Type `t` that is passed to the function will allways be a pointer type)